# Process 46,000 rows of a document in groups of 1000 using C# and Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code below that executes.  IT has 46,000 records in the text file that i need to process and insert into the database.  It takes FOREVER if i just call it directly and loop one at a time.

I was trying to use LINQ to pull every 1000 rows or so and throw it into a thread so I could proces 3000 rows at once and cut the processing time.  I can't figure it out though. so I need some help.

Any suggestions would be welcome.  Thank You in advance.

```
var reader = ReadAsLines(tbxExtended.Text);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var dt = new DataTable();

        string headerNames = "Long|list|of|strings|"                                  
        var headers = headerNames.Split('|');
        foreach (var header in headers)
            dt.Columns.Add(header);

        var records = reader.Skip(1);
        foreach (var record in records)
            dt.Rows.Add(record.Split('|'));

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.AcceptChanges();

        ProcessSmallList(ds);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for high performance then look at the [SqlBulkInsert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) if you are using SqlServer. The performance is significantly better than Insert row by row.

Here is an example using a custom CSVDataReader that I used for a project, but any [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) compatible Reader, DataRow[] or DataTable can be used as a parameter into WriteToServer, [SQLDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx), [OLEDBDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.aspx) etc.

```
Dim sr As CSVDataReader
Dim sbc As SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy
sbc = New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(mConnectionString, SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock Or SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity)
sbc.DestinationTableName = "newTable"
'sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 0

sr = New CSVDataReader(parentfileName, theBase64Map, ","c)
sbc.WriteToServer(sr)
sr.Close()
```

There are quite a number of options available. (See the link in the item)

Comment: @Nebseb: `SqlBulkCopy` works with `DataTable`, so prepare the data first, then perform the insert

Comment: I've never used SqlBulkCopy do you have an example ?

Comment: @Nebseb  -> why dont you accept the answer if it helps, or update the question if more information is required?

Answer (score 1):

To bulk insert data into a database, you probably should be using that database engine's bulk-insert utility (e.g. bcp in SQL Server).  You might want to first do the processing, write out the processed data into a separate text file, then bulk-insert into your database of concern.

If you *really* want to do the processing on-line and insert on-line, memory is also a (small) factor, for example:

1. ReadAllLines reads the whole text file into memory, creating 46,000 strings.  That would occupying a sizable chunk of memory.  Try to use ReadLines instead which returns an IEnumerable and return strings one line at a time.
2. Your dataset may contain all 46,000 rows in the end, which will be slow in detecting changed rows.  Try to Clear() the dataset table right after insert.

I believe the slowness you observed actually came from the dataset. Datasets issue one INSERT statement *per new record*, which means that you won't be saving anything by doing Update() 1,000 rows at a time or one row at a time.  You still have 46,000 INSERT statements going to the database, which makes it slow.

In order to improve performance, I'm afraid LINQ can't help you here, since the bottleneck is with the 46,000 INSERT statements.  You should:

1. Forgo the use of datasets
2. Dynamically create an INSERT statement in a string
3. Batch the update, say, 100-200 rows per command
4. Dynamically build the INSERT statement with multiple VALUE statments
5. Run the SQL command to insert 100-200 rows per batch

If you insist on using datasets, you don't have to do it with LINQ -- LINQ solves a different type of problems.  Do something like:

```
// code to create dataset "ds" and datatable "dt" omitted
// code to create data adaptor omitted

int count = 0;

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filename)) {
    // Do processing based on line, perhaps split it
    dt.AddRow(...);
    count++;

    if (count >= 1000) {
        adaptor.Update(dt);
        dt.Clear();
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

This will improve performance somewhat, but you're never going to approach the performance you obtain by using dedicated bulk-insert utilities (or function calls) for your database engine.

Unfortunately, using those bulk-insert facilities will make your code less portable to another database engine.  This is the trade-off you'll need to make.

Comment: Ideally i could just create smaller datasets that i pass to my insert functions.  Just now sure how I would do that.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. Question:

Comment: How would I get the headers into each table ? with the method above?  I am using Entity for my data interaction, so once i've maniplated my data, i create the entity object call save changes after i do an insert.  but the easiest way to get the columns i want is by name, so the first row of my datatable using linq is the name of the column.

Comment: @Nebseb, you are mixing a number of technologies here. Your question is about performance in inserting large number of records. And it appears that you're using DataSets (doesn't look like Entity Framework to me).

Comment: That is because in my example you see only my call to that part

Comment: ProcessSmallList(ds); is the part where i send it the dataset, and loop through it with entity.

Comment: I would definitely avoid Entity Framework for this task.  It is an ORB layer and definitely is *not* designed for high-performance bulk inserts.  Actually it will be the slowest because you are first creating an object, then the ORB will sync the object to the database while keeping track of all its changes.  You'll end up having 46,000 objects, tracking to 46,000 rows in the database, inserted **one bye one** through a LINQ->eSQL->SQL multi-layer mapper! Really, I **can't** think of a **slower** way to insert 46,000 records!

Comment: Just because you use EF for your database doesn't mean you *have* to use it for bulk inserts as well.  The tool has to be appropriate for the task at hand.